# How to get binary data in Worklight Web client

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm making Web client app for MofileFirstPlatform 8.0, and need to download a binary file via MFF adapter call. The MFF adapter returns binary data as the response, it is like

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="20170517191000051.zip"
Content-Length: 1016
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Date: Wed, 17 May 2017 10:10:51 GMT

binary data
```

To call the adapter, WLResourceRequest send method is used, 
but binary data of the response seems to set to respnseText attribute as javascript string. How can I get binary data?

Answer (score 0):

Data returned by a back-end service for a MobileFirst HTTP adapter must be in XML, HTML, JSON, or plain text format.  This is specified in the documentation, [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_http_adapters.html).

If the back end won't do this for you, my suggestion would be to put some type of proxy between the MFP Server and the back end, to intercept the traffic and re-encode it for you in transit.

Comment: Thanks. We'll change the design such that server will returns base64 encoded data.